# CMFCButton with Vista Style

Tags: c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I can't seem to get a CMFCButton to be displayed in Vista style in a dialog box application. I'm using VS2008 with MFC Feature Pack.

Here are some steps to reproduce my problem:

- Create a new MFC Project;
- Specify a Dialog based project.
- Add two buttons to the main dialog.
- Add a variable for each button. Make one of the variables a CButton, the other one a CMFCButton.
- Compile and run.

[test app picture http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/3/testapp.png](http://img7.imageshack.us/img7/3/testapp.png)

As you can see, the CButton has the correct style but the CMFCButton does not.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `CMFCButton` has the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style set by default - you can remove it in the `OnInitDialog()` for your dialog:

```
mfcButton.ModifyStyle(BS_OWNERDRAW, 0, 0);
```

However, removing the owner draw style results in many of the methods of CMFCButton being rendered useless (e.g. SetTextColor). You can get the button to render using the current windows theme by setting up the visual manager:

```
CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerWindows));
```

This is done instead of the `ModifyStyle` above, resulting in buttons that fit the default style but still have the newer rendering features.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. But, does this mean I won't have access to CMFCButton specific features, like changing text color?

Comment: Good point - turns out there is another way, answer updated with details.