# Changing the style of CMFCMenuButton look like a regular button on my dialog

Tags: mfc, popupmenubutton

I have a [`CMFCMenuButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcmenubutton-class?view=msvc-160) control on my dialog:

```
    CONTROL         "Lookup",IDC_MFCMENUBUTTON_LOOKUP_PUBLISHER,
                    "MfcMenuButton",WS_TABSTOP,106,254,45,14
```

I initialize it like this:

```
m_menuLookupPublisher.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU_LOOKUP_PUBLISHER);
m_btnLookupPublisher.m_hMenu = m_menuLookupPublisher.GetSubMenu(0)->GetSafeHmenu();
```

It works fine:

[image]

---

## Update

I have added some extra code (based on answer provided to me):

```
m_menuLookupPublisher.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU_LOOKUP_PUBLISHER);
m_btnLookupPublisher.m_hMenu = m_menuLookupPublisher.GetSubMenu(0)->GetSafeHmenu();
m_btnLookupPublisher.m_nFlatStyle = CMFCButton::BUTTONSTYLE_SEMIFLAT;
m_btnLookupPublisher.m_bDrawFocus = FALSE;
```

This improves the look and feel of the button now, but it is still not 100% the same. Here is what it looks like now when it does not have focus:

[image]

It is just the way the border is displayed that is not correct. `EnableWindowsThemeing` is `TRUE` by default so I am not sure what else I need to do here.

What's annoying is that in the VS IDE it looks fine:

[image]

My question concerns the visual display of the menu button. The border looks different that the other buttons. Can it be made to look the same without too much work?

---

## Update

I stumbled on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465549/cmfcbutton-with-vista-style) which is now pointing me in the right direction. If I add this code:

```
m_btnLookupPublisher.ModifyStyle(BS_OWNERDRAW, 0, 0);
```

Then is draws the border correctly etc. but renders other aspects of the button useless so it is not a viable solution. But the remainder of the answer is what I needed:

CMFCVisualManager::SetDefaultManager(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMFCVisualManagerWindows));

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about 3D look? Then you need to specify "flat" style `BUTTONSTYLE_FLAT`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class?view=msvc-160#m_nflatstyle

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had not tried. If I use `FLAT` then the button by design has no rectangle unless it has focus. If I use `SEMIFLAT` it is better still not exactly like the buttons visually. I guess they are just rendered differently.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle If you want them to match, make the other two buttons also `CMfcButton` (no `Menu`)

Comment: No. I have many dialogs in my app. Only two use these menu buttons. I am not changing them all just for this cosmetic issue.

Comment: Please see updated question.